# How to configure Solr for name searches

Tags: solr

I'm trying to create a searchable list of names (1M names+) and need some loose matching for the names. I've tried a few ways of configuring the server/querying the instance, but either ONLY exact matches are returned, or I get huge, inappropriate result sets missing the exact matches.

I'm new to Solr, is there a good example of doing this, or at least a good starting point I can work from to achieve what I need?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Solution in the end was down to my query - the setup was correct, and I did use the PhoneticFilterFactory, but I constructed bad/inaccurate queries. The Comment/link by mindas did contain what was required to sort this. Cheers folks for the assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [fuzzy searches](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html). They provide [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is what you refer as "loose matching".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search similar sounding names you can also check [PhoneticFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory)